# Why would .each work for one class name but not another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting jQuery to behave.  Code like this works:

```
<script>
var createTablesImpl = function(index, value) {
    $(value).prepend("<div>FOO</div>");
};
$(".yesPagingTable").each(createTablesImpl);
</script>

<div class="yesPagingTable">
    foo
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

But this fails (and by "failing" I mean "foo" is rendered but "FOO" is not):

```
<script>
var createTablesImpl = function(index, value) {
    $(value).prepend("<div>FOO</div>");
};
$(".yesPagingTableX").each(createTablesImpl);
</script>

<div class="yesPagingTableX">
    foo
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

I don't have any css classes defined in my project that I'm aware of (i.e. as far as I know one of these variables is defined in css somewhere and the other isn't).

Comment: There is nothing fundamental to the name of the class that could cause this. Since the rest of the code is identical it must be something wrong in a part of your code that we can't see. More information is required.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing and what do you expect to see? "This fails" is not precise enough for us to be able to help.

Comment: If what you say is true, my guess is that it has to do with not having the wrapping your jQuery like `$(function(){ /*code here*/ });` Maybe that `X` just takes long enough to read that the Element does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your javascript is executed before the HTML is rendered. Perhaps add document ready. Your script will wait untill all HTML is loaded.

```
<script>        
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var createTablesImpl = function(index, value) {
            $(value).prepend("<div>FOO</div>");
        };
        $(".yesPagingTableX").each(createTablesImpl);
    });
</script>

<div class="yesPagingTableX">
    foo
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Dais.  That was exactly what was going on.  It was so frustrating.